# What MA (MFA?) is needed to become an English / Creative Writing professor at a CC?

Tags: job-search

all!

So, this might be ridiculous, and you can feel free to laugh me out, but I'm trying to figure out a new life path. I've spent the last decade as a flight attendant for a major airline, and now I'm at a perfect point to go back to school and get a masters degree. (My bachelors is in Criminal Justice, but I'm working through English prerequisites for the MA below.) I also write fiction on the side--I'm agented, have one book getting traditionally published, and two more on submission with the Big 5 in NYC.

I was looking at Western Governors University to get an MA in Teaching English (Secondary), with the hopes that I could wiggle my way into adjunct or something and find full-time from there. But I just spoke with a friend who's a professor at a university in California, and she doesn't think this degree would help me. (Lacking the 18 credit hours in the core subject, for one, I think? But it's hard to tell; WGU doesn't number their classes like the rest of colleges do...)

Now I'm feeling pretty depressed. If this degree won't actually help me, why bother pursuing it? But an MFA seems like a waste of time and money, especially for someone who's already getting published through years of hard work--for free. :(

How should I proceed? I think teaching English sounds AMAZING, and I'm so ready for a career change. But I don't want to waste my time and money pursuing a masters that ultimately won't help me. This is so intimidating... I'd appreciate any insight!

Thank you! <3

Comment: Community colleges vary quite a bit from place to place.  If you have a particular place in mind, check the profiles of recently hired faculty.  I think you will find the competition is quite vigorous.  You might find most of the new faculty have PhDs from prominent universities.

Comment: Also, you will probably find the pay is terrible.

Comment: Secondary is high school, not college (that's tertiary), so your friend is probably right. Would you consider teaching high school, though?

Comment: WGU is not academically reputable and no CC would honestly consider a degree from them meaningful.  If they are desperate (and very rarely is a CC desperate for an English instructor these days) they'll consider that it satisfies their on-paper requirements.  @AnonymousPhysicist is basically correct.